# How to display a date?

Tags: dates

At least for the United states, what is the best way to display a date (of just year month and day) to the user? What order? should the month be fully typed out, the acronym, or just a number?

Comment: In what context? If you're filing for a divorce it's going to be one format, but showing your birthday off on Facebook is likely to be another. Context is key here.

Comment: There's a list of stuff that's identified by the date it was made. It's an informal situation, and the user doesn't have to enter it in.

Answer (score 5):

`YYYY-MM-DD` is [the standard date format](http://xkcd.com/1179/), but almost nobody knows it.

My personal preference for clarity is `DD/MMM/YYYY` with the month as a three-letter abbreviation.

If I were making an app, though, I'd use whatever format is standard on the user's device, as per locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends so much on context.  As JonW stated on a legal document will be different from an informal

You say list and date made.  If you want to compare dates then I find YYYY-MM-DD effective as sort by date goes from left to right.  A 4 digit year makes it clear that it is year.  And do 1 as 01 so  09 is left to right sort before 10.  And I even use fixed width font.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States,  MM/DD/YY or MM/DD/YYYY are accepted norms.
US puts month first, where a lot of the rest of the world puts day first.

Comment: I'll never understand why `▄▂█` seemed more sensible than `▂▄█` or `█▄▂` :D Apparently it's because dates are read as "December 5th, 2014" but if that's the case then why are prices listed as 12.34$ and not 12$23¢?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - because when this format came around the year was "understood." So it goes month then day AND if year is required add the year. This made a lot of sense in the 19th C. It makes little sense now - but languages aren't designed, they evolve.

Comment: @Mayo Ah, that makes sense. Now evolve, you silly Americans! :p I kid, I am aware that British English has some very bizarre oddities as well ^_^